# Tensorflow.js consecutive predictions much slower than single prediction

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, tensorflow.js

I have an application in which I want to continuously make and process predictions. I have a function that makes a prediction and does something with the result:

```
makeProcessPrediction(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      let prediction : any = this.model.predict(this.input_tensor);
      prediction.data().then((data_array) => {
              //... do something with prediction here
          }
      prediction.dispose();
      resolve('resolved');
      });
    });
}
```

Now if I make a single call to makeProcessPrediction, the prediction takes about 80 ms. But if I call it in a loop like this:

```
while(condition){
    await this.makeProcessPrediction();
}
```

Suddenly, the predictions take a lot longer, up to 140 ms. If I stop the loop and make another 'single' prediction, takes again around 80 ms.

I was hoping someone can explain me why this happens and perhaps what I can do to speed up the predictions.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the fact that some tensors are not disposed in memory. Could you please add the output of tf.memory() ?

Comment: Interesting, tf.memory outputs for some iterations:
```{unreliable: false, numBytesInGPU: 41380, numTensors: 163, numDataBuffers: 109, numBytes: 5325648}```
and for other iterations it outputs
```{unreliable: false, numBytesInGPU: 5284260, numTensors: 163, numDataBuffers: 109, numBytes: 5325648}``` 

I do not notice a pattern or a relation between prediction times and the numBytesInGPU. Except for flipping back and forth between these two different numbers for numBytesInGPU, there is no change or increase in the numbers, which I would expect for a memory leak?

Comment: I think the fact that you are retrieving the data stored in the gpu by using `data()` is taking too much time as your gpu data is increasing. But could you please share the architecture of your model ?

Comment: The model follows a U-net architecture, it's fully convolutional and I use it for image manipulation. It has 2 layers of encoding, an encoded layer and 2 layers of decoding. Are there other methods than ```data()``` that would be more appropriate to get the data off the gpu?

Comment: WOW you were right about ```data()```! I have now used ```dataSync()``` and the model runs super stable at a little below 80 ms!!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad it helped !

Comment: Hi Vera, I am trying to implement a FCN (UNet without the skips) and can't get it working in TFJS. Can you share how you encoded your labels (One-hot, single map, etc) and loss function? I've an open question waiting for an answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600956/fully-convolutional-network

Comment: Hi @Austin I noticed your comment a bit late but I'm glad to see that you were able to solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

**Try moving the GPU load.**  Actively calling the prediction data into JavaScript using `data()` allows you to pile up some promises, and likely clog your GPU pipe.

Moving to the synchronous method [`dataSync()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.dataSync) will properly process the GPU memory in the main thread.  While this will block your UI interaction, the speed should just as quick.